# How to write a javascript plugin without jQuery

Tags: javascript, prototype

Writing plugins with jQuery is relatively easy, just use $.fn and you're on your way. Like so:

```
$.fn.analyse = function() {
...
}
```

But what if you're not able to use jQuery?

Let's say I want to be able to use the following code:

```
document.querySelector("#mydiv").analyse();
```

I could go about it like this:

```
Object.prototype.analyse = function() {
...
}
```

But from what I understand it is frowned upon!

Comment: Then you just write a function which accepts a DOM element.

Comment: What exactly is your question?   You could make an object type that replaces jQuery and modify that -- you would just need a bit of plumbing to do selection I guess.

Comment: @Hogan Sorry for the late answer. The question is: What is the preferred way to extend the functionality of an object if `Object.prototype.extension` is frowned upon?

Comment: You can learn from the original (annotated) jQuery source code how to model your code - http://genius.it/ejohn.org/files/jquery-original.html

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Here's something to get you started:

```
var proto_methods = {
    analyse: function() {
        var node = this.node;

        // ...
    }
}, wrap, _wrap;

_wrap = function(selector) { this.node = document.querySelector(selector); };
_wrap.prototype = proto_methods;

wrap = function(selector) {
    return new _wrap(selector);
};
```

Use it like this:

```
wrap("#mydiv").analyse();
```

Use this if you want to add more plugins (and it's a little more object-oriented):

```
var pack = {
    binder: [{}]
};

pack.query_bind = function( bound ) {
    if (bound) pack.binder[1] = bound;
};

pack.fn = function( attributes ) {
    for (var i in attributes) pack.binder[0][i] = attributes[i];
};

var _wrap = function(selector) {
    this.node = /^(#|.)\w+/.test(selector) ? pack.binder[1](selector) : {};
};

_wrap.prototype = pack.binder[0];

var wrap = function(selector) {
    pack.query_bind(document.querySelector.bind(document));
    return new _wrap(selector);
};

wrap.fn = pack.fn;

wrap.fn({
    cool: function() {},
    nice: function() {}
});

wrap('#mydiv').cool();
```

You can call `wrap.fn` at any time and the prototype will be updated.

However, note that this is not a true replacement for jQuery as there are a lot of things that I have not included in this code. The `wrap` function is not as advanced and useful as jQuery's `$` in many ways.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks... It's helped me a lot... How to set options in this?

Comment: would you care to comment each section, explaining why you chose to do it the way it is? right now it's just a dump of code, with functions calling eachother and creating instances. it's not very self-explainable

Answer (score 4):

Just wrote boilerplate. It have no own selector logic because It's designed for library on top of D3.js which already have own selector engine.
https://gist.github.com/turboMaCk/34bde8e744f5921be0c4